# Presentation of the special linear group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\cong G=\langle a,b|a^4=1,a^2b^{-3}=1\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-presentation, linear-groups

I'm trying to show that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\cong G=\langle a,b|a^4=1,a^2b^{-3}=1\rangle$.

For this, I defined a homomorphism $f$ from $G$ into $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ 
by $$f(a)=\begin{bmatrix}0& -1\\1& 0\end{bmatrix},\ \ f(b)=\begin{bmatrix}0& -1\\1& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

I proved that it is surjective, but have no idea to prove it is injective.

My text book suggests every word $g \in G$ can be written as $g=a^{2i}a^{p_1}b^{q_1}a^{p_2}b^{q_2}\cdots$ where $p_j=0,1$ and $q_j=0,1,2$, so one can use the fact that every word is equivalent to exactly one reduced word for $\mathbb{Z_2}*\mathbb{Z_3}$.

I showed the words in $G$ can be written as the above, but don't know how to apply the uniqueness of a reduced word to prove the injectivity.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $a^4=a^2b^{-3}$ in your presentation?

Comment: @Alan I fixed it. $\langle a,b|a^4=1,a^2b^{-3}=1\rangle$

Comment: The standard method is to use the ping-pong lemma. I would recommend looking it up rather than trying to do it yourself.